# itunesconnect rejected Crash Report (Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa, ipad

I have submitted my app recently after testing on ipad air 2 and iphone 5 but apple continues to complain that my app is crashing on both ipad and iphone while i could not produce such a case on my side could you please help me geting the error by seeing this crash log pasted below

```
  Incident Identifier: 593E4393-0460-4041-9CD8-D88A38CA9D44
    CrashReporter Key:   ee845363e6ccd96145c8c85e7eba3147b616681f
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    process:             Biology Quiz [31229]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B9757D1B-E055-409A-
    B251-F65BEE5FC249/Biology Quiz.app/Biology Quiz
    Identifier:          xxx.xxxx.xxxxx
    Version:             1.0 (1)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2015-06-22 08:05:03.603 -0700
    Launch Time:         2015-06-22 08:04:58.595 -0700
    OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
    Report Version:      105
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18604c2d8 0x1978700e4 0x186053290 0x186050154 0x185f52ccc 0x1000b84fc 0x1000b0ca8 0x18aa8cc84 0x18aa8c994 0x18ac2f25c 0x18ab41ef0 0x18ab41cbc 0x18ab41c3c 0x18aa89760 0x18a3d1e1c 0x18a3cc884 0x18a3cc728 0x18a3cbebc 0x18a3cbc3c 0x18aa8b6f4 0x186004240 0x1860034e4 0x186001594 0x185f2d2d4 0x18f7436fc 0x18aaf2fac 0x1000c14bc 0x197eeea08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007270 0x197fec000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a516c 0x1980a0000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197f7eb14 0x197f1c000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019703d414 0x19703c000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019705cb88 0x19703c000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001978703bc 0x197868000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197059bb0 0x19703c000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197059474 0x19703c000 + 119924
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197870200 0x197868000 + 33280
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018605328c 0x185f24000 + 1241740
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186050150 0x185f24000 + 1229136
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f52cc8 0x185f24000 + 191688
12  Biology Quiz                    0x00000001000b84f8 0x10009c000 + 115960
13  Biology Quiz                    0x00000001000b0ca4 0x10009c000 + 85156
14  UIKit                           0x000000018aa8cc80 0x18aa7c000 + 68736
15  UIKit                           0x000000018aa8c990 0x18aa7c000 + 67984
16  UIKit                           0x000000018ac2f258 0x18aa7c000 + 1782360
17  UIKit                           0x000000018ab41eec 0x18aa7c000 + 810732
18  UIKit                           0x000000018ab41cb8 0x18aa7c000 + 810168
19  UIKit                           0x000000018ab41c38 0x18aa7c000 + 810040
20  UIKit                           0x000000018aa8975c 0x18aa7c000 + 55132
21  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a3d1e18 0x18a3c4000 + 56856
22  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a3cc880 0x18a3c4000 + 34944
23  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a3cc724 0x18a3c4000 + 34596
24  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a3cbeb8 0x18a3c4000 + 32440
25  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a3cbc38 0x18a3c4000 + 31800
26  UIKit                           0x000000018aa8b6f0 0x18aa7c000 + 63216
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018600423c 0x185f24000 + 918076
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860034e0 0x185f24000 + 914656
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186001590 0x185f24000 + 906640
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2d2d0 0x185f24000 + 37584
31  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f7436f8 0x18f738000 + 46840
32  UIKit                           0x000000018aaf2fa8 0x18aa7c000 + 487336
33  Biology Quiz                    0x00000001000c14b8 0x10009c000 + 152760
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197eeea04 0x197eec000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197fecc24 0x197fec000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197ed1e6c 0x197ec0000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197ec3998 0x197ec0000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007c78 0x197fec000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a12d8 0x1980a0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0eec 0x1980a0000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007c78 0x197fec000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a12d8 0x1980a0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0eec 0x1980a0000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007c78 0x197fec000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a12d8 0x1980a0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0eec 0x1980a0000 + 3820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007c78 0x197fec000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a12d8 0x1980a0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0eec 0x1980a0000 + 3820

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197fece0c 0x197fec000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197fecc84 0x197fec000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186003720 0x185f24000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186001674 0x185f24000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2d2d0 0x185f24000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f7f358 0x185f24000 + 373592
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000186938364 0x1868f0000 + 295780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a3dc4 0x1980a0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a3d20 0x1980a0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0ef4 0x1980a0000 + 3828

Thread 7 name:  WebThread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001980070c0 0x197fec000 + 110784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a1490 0x1980a0000 + 5264
2   WebCore                         0x000000019492a670 0x194878000 + 730736
3   WebCore                         0x000000019492a5d4 0x194878000 + 730580
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860042a0 0x185f24000 + 918176
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018600122c 0x185f24000 + 905772
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186001700 0x185f24000 + 907008
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2d2d0 0x185f24000 + 37584
8   WebCore                         0x0000000194928890 0x194878000 + 723088
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a3dc4 0x1980a0000 + 15812
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a3d20 0x1980a0000 + 15648
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0ef4 0x1980a0000 + 3828

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198007c78 0x197fec000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a12d8 0x1980a0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001980a0eec 0x1980a0000 + 3820
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash so that the numbers turn into something useful, especially frames 12 and 13.

Comment: i can't understand what you meant. can you please describe

Comment: If you have an archive of your app, Xcode should do it automatically if you drag the crash log onto its icon.  There are also a lot of blog pages for how to use 'symbolicatecrash' manually.  Here's one: https://marmalade.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202865223--M0102-How-to-symbolicate-iOS-crash-reports  I trust manual more than automatic.

Comment: when i'm download crash report form itunes. its .text format and when i'm open device and" view device logs" in xcode.not know how we open my crash report .can you help me?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem, How can I solve this ?

Comment: Did u solve this??? @VineeshTP Can u guide me pls?

Comment: Did u solve this?  @FahimParkar

Comment: @McDonal_11 : its 2015 question bro.. I don't recollect...

Comment: @McDonal_11 : I would suggest upload app on testflight. you will find a reason for that...

Comment: @McDonal_11 : Do u have push in your app?

Comment: Finally I have found out. UIView class issue. Thanks for ur reply :)